# Transformation the screen coordinates to stage coordinates

Tags: java, libgdx

When I call this line `Gdx.input.getY();` The screen origin is the top left corner, but my stage coordinates in buttom left corener. How can I transform the screen coordinates to stage coordinates ? (WITHOUT using camera) i.e. How can I make the screen origin in the bottom left corner ?

Comment: You can't do it without the camera. The translation between the two is *defined* by the camera. Unless, I suppose, you know your camera is set to the same dimensions of the screen and is positioned with 0,0 in the bottom left corner. Then you can simply subtract Y from the screen height.

Comment: Ummm. Ok, thanx for reply on my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **screenToStageCoordinates** Stage method. The example of getting input position Vector is:

```
    Vector2 position = stage.screenToStageCoordinates( new Vector2(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY()) );
```

Comment: Perfect Answer. Really I'm looking forward your answers always.
THANK YOU SO MUCH